# Is there an equivalent of Junit5 TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider that can be used on class level?

Tags: java, junit5

I use TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider as JUnit 5 extension to handle some configuration of user profile when running a test.

Something like this

```
@MyExtension({Config.VALUE_A, Config.VALUE_B})
void myTest(UserContext context) {
 // my test
}
```

This allow me to executed the test multiple time with different user configuration.

I want to allow to do the same things at class level, like this:

```
@MyExtension({Config.VALUE_A, Config.VALUE_B})
class MyTestSuite {

   void myTest(UserContext context) {
     // my test
   }

   void myTest2(UserContext context) {
     // my test
   }
}
```

So that each of my tests inside test suite is invoked multiple times.
Is there an equivalent of Junit5 TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider that can be used on class level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no support for parameterized test classes in JUnit Jupiter.

For details, see the following open issues on the subject.

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878